# TSQL to get XML data into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

How can I write query which would output this below?

```
ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE"

DECLARE @x XML;
SET @x = N'<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>ALTER_TABLE</EventType>
  <PostTime>2015-05-19T14:01:46.930</PostTime>
  <SPID>52</SPID>
  <ServerName>computer1</ServerName>
  <LoginName>domain\user</LoginName>
  <UserName>dbo</UserName>
  <DatabaseName>DBA</DatabaseName>
  <SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
  <ObjectName>Table_1</ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType>
  <AlterTableActionList>
    <Create>
      <Columns>
        <Name>c8</Name>
      </Columns>
    </Create>
  </AlterTableActionList>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD c8 INT NULL</CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>';
```

Comment: In title you said "*get XML data into a column*", but the expected output is string containing attribute name-value pairs. So what do you want to be the output actually, string or columns?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant is I needed a SELECT that would rip the SetOptions values out from the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a hack, but this should work:

```
DECLARE @x XML;
SET @x = N'<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>ALTER_TABLE</EventType>
  <PostTime>2015-05-19T14:01:46.930</PostTime>
  <SPID>52</SPID>
  <ServerName>computer1</ServerName>
  <LoginName>domain\user</LoginName>
  <UserName>dbo</UserName>
  <DatabaseName>DBA</DatabaseName>
  <SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
  <ObjectName>Table_1</ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType>
  <AlterTableActionList>
    <Create>
      <Columns>
        <Name>c8</Name>
      </Columns>
    </Create>
  </AlterTableActionList>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD c8 INT NULL</CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>';


SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), @X.query('(//TSQLCommand/SetOptions)')),'<SetOptions', ''), '/>', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get string containing all attributes of `<SetOption>` as output, one possible way is using XQuery for loop like so :

```
SELECT @x.query('
   for $attr in /EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/SetOptions/@*
   (: return value in format : attribute_name="attribute_value" :)
   return concat(local-name($attr),''="'',$attr,''"'')
')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1045)**

**output :**

```
ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE"
```

**brief explanation :**

- `/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/SetOptions` : specify path to `<SetOption>` element
- `/@*` : get all attributes from current context element (it is `<SetOption>` element in this case)
- `(: some comment here :)` : [XQuery comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186281.aspx)
- `concat()` : concatenates all parameters into single string result
- `local-name()` : return element local name (a.k.a XML tag name)
- note that `''` within `concat()` means simply `'`. Single quotes need to be escaped in this situation, and it is done in SQL Server by doubling each of them.

**for reference :**

- [MSDN : FLWOR (for, let, where, order by, return) Statement and Iteration (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx)

Comment: That's the best way to go; I tried to get it to work, but it was breaking for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely missing you're situation, but is this what you need Mark:

```
SELECT 
'
    DECLARE @x XML;
    SET @x = N''<?xml version = "1.0"?>
    <EVENT_INSTANCE>
      <EventType>ALTER_TABLE</EventType>
      <PostTime>2015-05-19T14:01:46.930</PostTime>
      <SPID>52</SPID>
      <ServerName>computer1</ServerName>
      <LoginName>domain\user</LoginName>
      <UserName>dbo</UserName>
      <DatabaseName>DBA</DatabaseName>
      <SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
      <ObjectName>Table_1</ObjectName>
      <ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType>
      <AlterTableActionList>
        <Create>
          <Columns>
            <Name>c8</Name>
          </Columns>
        </Create>
      </AlterTableActionList>
      <TSQLCommand>
        <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
        <CommandText>ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD c8 INT NULL</CommandText>
      </TSQLCommand>
    </EVENT_INSTANCE>'';
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also be looking to dynamically generate the event from the current schema. Maybe something down along these lines?

```
    SELECT
'
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>ALTER_TABLE</EventType>
  <PostTime>2015-05-19T14:01:46.930</PostTime>
  <SPID>52</SPID>
  <ServerName>computer1</ServerName>
  <LoginName>domain\user</LoginName>
  <UserName>' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '</UserName>
  <DatabaseName>DBA</DatabaseName>
  <SchemaName>dbo</SchemaName>
  <ObjectName>' + TABLE_NAME + '</ObjectName>
  <ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType>
  <AlterTableActionList>
    <Create>
      <Columns>
        <Name>      
        ' 
        +
                (
                SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Names, 'lt;', '<name>'), ',&','</name>' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  + '</name>' FROM
                (
                SELECT 
                  t1.Table_Name,
                  STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + '<' + t2.COLUMN_NAME   
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2
                    WHERE t2.Table_Name = t1.Table_Name
                    FOR XML PATH (''))
                  ,1,2,'') AS Names
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t1
                WHERE t1.TABLE_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME
                GROUP BY t1.Table_Name
                ) I1

                )
        +
        '
        </Name>
      </Columns>
    </Create>
  </AlterTableActionList>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 ADD c8 INT NULL</CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>'
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```